# How to create custom role in azure active directory using graph api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory

I would like to create custom roles in azure active directory for an application (Application Level).I tried using graph api and i got exception as "The context is already tracking the entity.".I am attaching my code below.Please find what is wrong.Please tell me how to add custom application roles.

```
    using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient;
    using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Extensions;
    using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using WebAppGraphAPI.Utils;

    namespace WebAppGraphAPI.Controllers
    {
        public class ApplicationRoleController : Controller
        {
            private static readonly string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];

            // GET: ApplicationRole
            public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
            {
                var roleList = new List<AppRole>();
                try
                {
                    ActiveDirectoryClient client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();
                    IPagedCollection<IApplication> pagedCollection = await client.Applications.Where(x => x.AppId == clientId).ExecuteAsync();

                    if (pagedCollection != null)
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            List<IApplication> applicationItemList = pagedCollection.CurrentPage.ToList();
                            foreach (IApplication application in applicationItemList)
                            {
                                roleList.Add((AppRole)application.AppRoles);
                            }
                            pagedCollection = await pagedCollection.GetNextPageAsync();
                        } while (pagedCollection != null && pagedCollection.MorePagesAvailable);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    if (Request.QueryString["reauth"] == "True")
                    {
                        //
                        // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request to get a new set of tokens.
                        // If the user still has a valid session with Azure AD, they will not be prompted for their credentials.
                        // The OpenID Connect middleware will return to this controller after the sign-in response has been handled.
                        //
                        HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
                            .Authentication.Challenge(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                    }

                    //
                    // The user needs to re-authorize.  Show them a message to that effect.
                    //
                    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "AuthorizationRequired";
                    return View(roleList);
                }
                return View(roleList);
            }

            /// <summary>
            ///     Creates a view to for adding a new <see cref="User" /> to Graph.
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns>A view with the details to add a new <see cref="User" /> objects</returns>
            public ActionResult CreateRole()
            {
                return View();
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<ActionResult> CreateRole(
                [Bind(
                    Include =
                        "DisplayName,Value"
                    )] AppRole role)
            {
                ActiveDirectoryClient client = null;
                try
                {
                    client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    if (Request.QueryString["reauth"] == "True")
                    {
                        //
                        // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request to get a new set of tokens.
                        // If the user still has a valid session with Azure AD, they will not be prompted for their credentials.
                        // The OpenID Connect middleware will return to this controller after the sign-in response has been handled.
                        //
                        HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
                            .Authentication.Challenge(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                    }

                    //
                    // The user needs to re-authorize.  Show them a message to that effect.
                    //
                    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "AuthorizationRequired";
                    return View();
                }

                try
                {
////Get Current application from active directory
                    IPagedCollection<IApplication> pagedCollection = await client.Applications.Where(x => x.AppId == clientId).ExecuteAsync();
                    var appObject = pagedCollection.CurrentPage.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
                    appObject.AppRoles.Add(role as AppRole);
                    ////
                    ////Am Getting Exception Here as "The context is already tracking the entity."....
                    ////
                    await client.Applications.AddApplicationAsync(appObject);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", exception.Message);
                    return View();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What version of the Graph Client Library are you using?  This seems like an error we were getting in older versions...

Comment: I was wondering that when i downloaded the latest nuget version of graph client library and when i checked the properties of graph dll,I found that the version is 1.0.0.0 and downloaded version is latest till now (2.0.5).Why is this happening?Is that the issue with nuget?Am using nuget version 2.8.3

Comment: Not sure about the last question. Are you using Visual Studio? Please can you confirm if using 2.0.5 has fixed your problem Ramesh?

Comment: Yes I am using visual studio.I somehow managed the problem by using graph api version 1.5 appending to graph url.But my question is that,then what is the use of using latest dll of azure graph client?Better than appending the api version with url,why can't it manage in the dll itself?After downloading 2.0.5 version of graph client from nuget,then from reference right click graph client dll,then in properties tab windows under version, you can find that it is not 2.0.5 and it is  1.0.0.0.This is my question now.

Comment: Hi Ramesh.  Sorry for any confusion. 2.0.5 is the version number of the nuget package.  You can manage the nuget packages for the solution by right clicking on the Solution, and selecting "Manage nuget packages for solution...".  In this dialog you'll see all the nuget packages that your solution uses. You should see the graph client library there, and the version details.  This is independent of the dll version number, which I don't believe we update currently.  I'll double check our build process here.  By using version 2.0.5, is the issue now resolved? Are you able to add custom roles now?

Comment: Hi am now able to define application roles.But i faced another problem.I cannot add user to application role programatically.When i tried to add, i found that approleassignment property of user is readonly. :(.Could you give a solution how to add a role to a user asap.

Comment: @Rames: How did u add roles in azure application from c#?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delayed response.  Here's how you can add an app role assignment to a user.  This code snippet is also part of our console app sample on github here: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/ConsoleApp-GraphAPI-DotNet.  You'll find other useful operations described in the sample.

```
        #region Assign Direct Permission
        try
        {
            User user =
                    (User)activeDirectoryClient.Users.ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
            if (appObject.ObjectId != null && user != null && newServicePrincpal.ObjectId != null)
            {
                AppRoleAssignment appRoleAssignment = new AppRoleAssignment();
                appRoleAssignment.Id = appRole.Id;
                appRoleAssignment.ResourceId = Guid.Parse(newServicePrincpal.ObjectId);
                appRoleAssignment.PrincipalType = "User";
                appRoleAssignment.PrincipalId = Guid.Parse(user.ObjectId);
                user.AppRoleAssignments.Add(appRoleAssignment);
                user.UpdateAsync().Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("User {0} is successfully assigned direct permission.", retrievedUser.DisplayName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Direct Permission Assignment failed: {0} {1}", e.Message,
                e.InnerException != null ? e.InnerException.Message : "");
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Dan. But i have few queries. 
What is the difference between ServicePrincipal and appObject?What is the importance of creating ServicePrincipal?

Comment: Good question.  So an application object is really an application DEFINITION/CONFIG.  It describes the identity configuration for your application.  The application definition lives in your (developer) tenant.  When a customer consents to your application, they get an instance of the application in their customer tenant, which we call a service principal. The customer can attach "policy" to this object, like assigning this application to users/groups, conditional access policies for the app (like requires MFA), and the like - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn132633.aspx.

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT : I have followed the console-app graph client app library.I can able to query all the roles which are specific to my applicaion but when I assign a role to the existing user[I haven't tried for new user] I am getting the error "Error Updating the user One or more errors occurred. Resource 'some random string' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."I have given all permissions in the configure page for this application.